# Chrome Developer Tools: Mobile devices preview shows shrinked

Tags: google-chrome, mobile

Since a few days, I can't preview any site as it should in Chrome's Developers Tools using Mobile Devices.

The website occupies only the 1/4 of the mobile space as in the screenshot and it's very annoying at least to say.

[image: Chrome - mobile device preview]

Googling it, I didn't manage to find anything relevant - as it's also not easy to describe this with a google search, so hopefully since SO is a developers site, I might find an answer here.

Is there anyone else having this issue? Any chance that I have make any changes in the dev tools that affect this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Adding a custom device with correct dpr is a workaround fix, but this must be addressed by Google

Comment: It got fixed on its own for me. Maybe Chrome was updated. My current version is 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit). But I didn't make a note for the version when I had the issue.